# Grafana on Ubuntu - local file permission denied

Tags: csv, ubuntu, permissions, grafana

I recently installed Grafana on my EC2 Ubuntu server, which worked well, and I got it running under my IP address and port 3000.

However, I have problems now accessing a local csv file that I have stored on the same EC2 server under `/home/ubuntu/file.csv`

Whenever I try to open it in Grafana under the csv plug-in I get the error that permission is denied. I already checked the file permissions with `namei - l`, which gives me the following answer:

```
f: /home/ubuntu/file.csv
drwxr-xr-x root   root   /
drwxr-xr-x root   root   home
drwxr-xr-x ubuntu ubuntu ubuntu
-rwxrwxrwx ubuntu ubuntu file.csv
```

What I checked on similar problems so far, it seems that the file.csv has the right permissions, but maybe the /home/ubuntu/ folder not.

Can somebody please help me?

Comment: Store your CSV file inside the folder ```/usr/share/grafana```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Changing the file rights with `chmod` didn't do the trick, but changing the owner (`chown`) of all folders leading to the file to "grafana" solved it:

```
sudo chown grafana `folder`
```